# How to display item meta data in email confirmation using woocommerce_order_item_meta_end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Our store sells software and we're adding a software voucher code to each purchased. Once the purchase is completed (via the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook) we generate the voucher code and add it to each item purchased via [wc_add_order_item_meta](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_order_item_meta.html) method.

Summarized code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'add_voucher_code');

function add_voucher_code( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item)   {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $item['qty']; $i++)  {
            $voucher_code = 'API request based on order information to get voucher code';
            wc_add_order_item_meta($item->get_id(), 'Voucher Code', $voucher_code);
        }
    }     
}
```

For some reason or another the item custom meta shows up on the order confirmation page, but doesn't in the confirmation email. (**problem 1** slaps forehead) So we're utilizing the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook to add it to the confirmation email. ([wc_get_order_item_meta](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html))

Summarized code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

    echo '<div>Voucher Code: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Voucher Code') .'</div>';
}
```

**Problem 2** is that added snippet of code shows on the both the order confirmation page (so now it shows twice) and in the order confirmation email. (slaps forehead again)

**Current Problem 2 Solution**
Right now we solved it by adding an if statement which is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications/52684694#52684694). Like so:

```
// Only on emails notifications
if( ! (is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )) {
    echo '<div>Voucher Code: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Voucher Code') .'</div>';
}
```

This feels like a band-aid fix and any insight/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you specifically using `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` for the placement or is utilizing another hook/filter a possibility?

Comment: Exactly. Since there needs to be a voucher code for each item ordered I don't think another hook could work. (but am open to it) I'm basing this on the WooCommerce standard hooks: [email confirmation hook visual guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this isn't getting much action I'll put our *band-aid* fix as the current solution.

**Problem 1 Solution**
The added item meta data shows on the order confirmation page and does not show on the confirmation email. We solved this by utilizing the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook to add the extra item meta.

**Problem 2 Solution**
Adding the item meta data via `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` to the confirmation 
 email also adds it to the confirmation page (visibly duplicating it). We solved this by adding an if statement suggested by [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications/52684694#52684694).

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! (is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )) {
        echo '<div>Voucher Code: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Voucher Code') .'</div>';
    }
}
```

**Resources**
[email confirmation hook visual guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/)
[wc_get_order_item_meta docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html)
[Filter out unwanted order item meta data from Woocommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications/52684694#52684694)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
As I understand from the source code there is another hook

> woocommerce_pre_payment_complete

which fixed the issue for me.
Hook *woocommerce_payment_complete* called after payment made and after order status change and after email trigger so it doesn't include updated metadata.
Hook *woocommerce_pre_payment_complete* calls after payment made but before order status change and before email sending. So it worked for me to add metadata into order item and display in email, order confirmation page, admin order view page correctly without using additional code for *woocommerce_order_item_meta_end*

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue today so I've posted an alternative solution [in response to the bug report for this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/24578#issuecomment-2015542571). It's a little bit nicer than the solution proposed here.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', function( $args ) {
    $refreshed_order = wc_get_order( $args['order'] );
    
    if( $refreshed_order ) {
        $args['order'] = $refreshed_order;
        $args['items'] = $refreshed_order->get_items();
    }
    
    return $args;
} );
```