# Changing the order item meta data in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders, email-notifications

I need to change/customize a specific order item meta data for WooCommerce email notifications, but I can't find a solution.

I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52684694/1354580), but it is for unsetting unneeded order item meta data from Woocommerce email notifications.

Can the mentioned code can be adapted for changing meta data for emails?

I tried with `$formatted_meta[$key] = 'new value';` but that does not give the desired result. Any advice?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'unset_specific_order_item_meta_data', 10, 2);
function unset_specific_order_item_meta_data($formatted_meta, $item){
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $formatted_meta;

    foreach( $formatted_meta as $key => $meta ){
        $formatted_meta[$key] = 'new value';
    }
    return $formatted_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to adjust these values ​​via the current hook you are using, you can do it like this:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data( $formatted_meta, $item ) {
    // Only on emails notifications
    if ( is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $formatted_meta;

    foreach ( $formatted_meta as $key => $meta ) {
        $formatted_meta[$key]->display_key = 'new key';
        $formatted_meta[$key]->display_value = 'new value';
    }
    
    return $formatted_meta;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 10, 2 );
```

---

However, know that instead of using the above hook the `woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key` & `woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value` filter hooks are better suited:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    // Only on emails notifications
    if ( is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $display_key;

    // Display key
    $display_key = 'My new key';
    
    return $display_key;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );

function filter_woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value( $display_value, $meta, $item ) {
    // Only on emails notifications
    if ( is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $display_value;

    // Display value
    $display_value = 'My new value';
        
    return $display_value;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', 10, 3 );
```

Then it is a matter of determining via if conditions which adjustments are specifically concerned, since these are currently generally applied via my answer

Comment: Worked for me. If wanting to modify a key, can use something like `if ( $meta->key === 'Booking Date' ) {
    $display_value = date( 'm.d.Y', strtotime( $meta->value ) );
  }`